# Heroku jar problems

Tags: heroku, deployment, jar

I created simple java app, built jar, and now I am trying to deploy it on heroku. The problem is that I can't setup right jdk version. I need jdk 17.0.2, but heroku provides only jdk 8 by default.
I use heroku java cli plugin (https://github.com/heroku/plugin-java), and according to the documentation I created Procfile in folder with my jar:

```
web: java $JAVA_OPTS -jar <myjar>.jar -v 17.0.2 $JAR_OPTS.
```

but nothing has changed.

I've also tried deploy my jar like this:

```
heroku deploy:jar <myjar>.jar -v 17.0.2 -a <appname>
heroku deploy:jar <myjar>.jar -a <appname> -v 17.0.2
```

instead of simple:

```
heroku deploy:jar <myjar>.jar -a <appname>
```

but it also did't help.
Since I'm trying to deploy jar, I can't use git and change jdk version by system.properties file. How can I solve this problem? Thanks for any help.

Comment: I ran into the same problem, but I couldn't find a way to customize the JDK by deploying a jar. I solved it temporarily by following the guides to deploy a java application (then versioning the whole project on git and adding the file system.properties). Here the links: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/customizing-the-jdk